# Count numbers in python loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to get a loop which will tell me the number of 0 in a array of 50 random intergers from 0 to 2 (not including 2). And which will then calculate random integers again for the number of zeroes obtained.

I tried doing it but I am getting stuck at the primary stages and it is getting frustrating so any help would be much appreciated.

```
from numpy.random import randint

n = 50

R = randint(0,2,n)

for i in R:
    True = 0
    print array(True)
```

But it doesn't return an array and I don't know how to count the number of 0's as I can't use the len function as I normally would.

I tried using the while loop as well but ran into similar problems

Answer (score 4):

Since your array contains only ones and zeroes, the count of zeroes will be obviously

```
num_zeroes = len(R) - sum(R)
```

Answer (score 2):

To count the `0`s in `R` you can just do

```
sum(not n for n in R)
```

The advantage of this is that it will work even if you have numbers other than only `1`s and `0`s in the array.

---

Thanks to eryksun for pointing this out: you can also do

```
numpy.sum(R == 0)
```

Comment: Vectorized: `numpy.sum(R == 0)`.

Comment: @user1778543 Sure - `not n` returns `1` if `n` is `0` and it returns `0` otherwise. `not n for n in R`: we loop over `R` and calculate `not n` for each element `n`, we then simply add these values with `sum` to obtain the total number of `0`s.

Answer (score 0):

Generating the array:

```
random_list = [random.randint(0,2) for x in xrange(50)]
```

number of 0's:

```
num_zeros = sum( 1 for x in random_list if x==0 )
```

generating the array again:

```
random_list = [random.randint(0,2) for x in xrange(num_zeros)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is something you are looking for:

```
from numpy.random import randint

n = 50

R = randint(0,2,n)

def get_number_of_zeros(x):
    return sum(0 == ele for ele in x)

while(len(R) > 0):
    number_of_zeros = get_number_of_zeros(R)
    print 'number of zeros is {}'.format(number_of_zeros)
    R = randint(0, 2, number_of_zeros)
```

Result:

```
number of zeros is 25
number of zeros is 11
number of zeros is 7
number of zeros is 4
number of zeros is 1
number of zeros is 1
number of zeros is 1
number of zeros is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, no need for loops and sums. If you have an array of integers, you can count the number of zeros (or any other individual number) like this:

```
>>> R = [ 0, 1, 5, 0, 0]
>>> print("There are", R.count(0), "zeros")
There are 3 zeros
```